# Clearest way to initialize module-level lists in Python

Tags: python, module, styles

I've got a situation where a module needs to do some simple, but slightly time consuming initialization. One of the end conditions is a pair of lists which will be filled out by the initialization; what's bugging me is that there's a conflict between the role of the lists - which are basically intended to be constants - and the need to actually initialize them.

I feel uneasy writing code like this:

```
 CONSTANT_LIST = []
 DIFFERENT_LIST = []

 for item in get_some_data_slowly():
      if meets_criteria_one(item): 
         CONSTANT_LIST.append(item)
         continue
      if meets_criteria_two(item):
         DIFFERENT_LIST.append(item)
```

Since the casual reader will see those lists in the position usually occupied by constants and may expect them to be empty.

OTOH, I'd be OK with the same under-the-hood facts if I could write this as a list comprehension:

```
 CONSTANT_LIST = [i for i in some_data() if criterion(i)]
```

and so on...  except that I need two lists drawn from the same (slightly time consuming) source, so two list comprehensions will make the code noticeably slower.

To make it worse, the application is such that hiding the constants behind methods:

```
__private_const_list = None
__other_private_list = None

def public_constant_list():
    if __private_const_list: return  __private_const_list 
    # or do the slow thing now and fill out both lists...
    # etc

def public_other_const_list():
    # same thing
```

is kind of silly since the likely use frequency is basically 1 per session.

As you can see it's not a rocket science issue but my Python sense is not tingling at all. Whats the appropriate pythonic pattern here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop is quite clear. Don't obfuscate it by being too clever. Just use comments to help explain

```
CONSTANT_LIST = []    # Put a comment here to tell the reader that these 
DIFFERENT_LIST = []   # are constants that are filled in elsewhere
"""
Here is an example of what CONSTANT_LIST looks like
...
Here is an example of what DIFFERENT_LIST looks like
...
"""


for item in get_some_data_slowly():
    if meets_criteria_one(item): 
        CONSTANT_LIST.append(item)
    elif meets_criteria_two(item):
        DIFFERENT_LIST.append(item)
```

Maybe use `elif` instead of `continue/if`